# Angular select does not update model properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

With my AngularJS application I have an `select` that is bound to the model.
When the user select an option from the list, the model is not updated.
When the users clicks on the same option again, the model is updated.

As you can understand this is not desired behaviour. In my test I replaced the `select` with a `<input type='text'>` and it works as expected. What is my problem here? I can't get it reproduced in JSFiddle, so I will post as many code as I think is relevant.

#### Index.html

This is were I get the proper template for every type of setable poperty.
So text-input gets an `input type='text'` and `frequenty` gets his template, a `select`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in propertyList">
    <ng-include src="getTemplate(item, formObject)"></ng-include>
</div>
```

#### Controller.coffee

Here the proper template is returned, and the selectable frequencies are set.

```
$scope.getTemplate = (prop, object) =>  
   if $builder.widgets.hasOwnProperty prop #Here it found the frequency dropdown template.
     return $builder.widgets[prop]               
   else if angular.isString propValue
        return 'templates/widgets/textInput.html'
   else if angular.isObject propValue
        return 'templates/widgets/formulas.html'
   return

$scope.frequencies = [
    "NONE"
    "DOCUMENT"
    "PERIOD"
    "COLUMN"
  ]
```

#### Frequencies.html

This is the problem area. The select displays the options, but when an option is clicked, the model is not updated. The weirdest thing is that the `formula.html` table is updated. This is because they are bound the the same formObject, but the model is not updated and the select is emptied. When I click the same option again, the `select` properly updates the model.

When you replace the `select` with the commented `input`, it workes flawless. But the user needs to select the frequencies and not type them.

```
<div>
    <!--<input ng-model="formObject[item]">-->
    <select data-ng-model="formObject[item]" data-ng-options="frequency for frequency in frequencies"></select>
</div>
```

#### Formulas.html

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col">title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key,row) in formObject.formulas">

                <th>{{key}}</th>
                <td ng-repeat="column in row track by $index">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="row[$index]"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this is clear enough, so I hope you can help me get this problem tackled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dot for the ng-model. 
SEe my explanation and a link to a more detail info here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850255/3687474

Comment: When I do that the result is the same.  
I replaced  `<select data-ng-model="formObject[item]" data-ng-options="freque....` with `<select data-ng-model="formObject.frequency" data-ng-options="freque....`

Comment: add a log please in HTML : "FREQUENCY: {{ formObject.frequency }}" to ensure that data is set or not

Comment: I did that, and the outcome is weird.
The `formulas.html` is updated, but the log in the HTML says nothing...
When I click the second time, the log is also updated to: FREQUENCY: DOCUMENT, by example.
_added after some more testing_
When I use the `input type=text` to choose the frequency, after every keystroke the log is updated